# Adder using Django

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to Django, trying to get this snippet code working as a adder.

```
"""Perform addition using Django"""

template = """
<form method="post" action=" ">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="a" > + <input type="text" name="b" >
    <input type="submit" value="="> <input type="text" name="result >
</form>"""
```

```
def add(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('a'):
        a = int(request.POST['a'])
        b = int(request.POST['b'])
        result = request.POST['result'] 

    else:
        a = 0
        b = 0
    t = Template(template)
    c = RequestContext(request, {'a': a, 'b': b, 'result': a+b})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

#url.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    url(r'^add/$', 'myapp.views.add'),   
)
```

[Django Adder](http://pastebin.com/tdZnU8Gv)

but was unable to get proper result rendered. Not too sure where it went wrong. 
Appreciated for any comments

Answer (score 1):

In your template, you're not filling in the `a`, `b`, and `result`. You also need the action to point somewhere. Also, you're missing a quote. Finally, use `get` instead of `post` because submitting the form doesn't change anything persistent, like the database:

```
template = Template("""
<form method="get" action="{% url add %}">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="a" value="{{a}}">
    + <input type="text" name="b" value="{{b}}">
    <input type="submit" value="=">
    <input type="text" name="result" value="{{result}}">
</form>""")
```

Your view doesn't need the `result` variable, and needs more error checking. Also, you don't need to create the `Template` every time:

```
def add(request):
    try:
        a = int(request.POST.get('a', 0))
    except:
        a = 0

    try:
        b = int(request.POST.get('b', 0))
    except:
        b = 0

    c = RequestContext(request, {'a': a, 'b': b, 'result': a + b})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(c))
```

In `url.py`, you need the name to make the `url` tag above work:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',      
    url(r'^add/$', 'myapp.views.add', name='add'),   
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- better not to have space in `action=" "`
- missing double quote `<input type="text" name="result >`
- the checking of `if request.POST.has_key('a')` is incomplete and error-prone. Plus, use `'a' in request.POST` instead of deprecated `has_key()`
- wrong logic of calculating `result`: remove the `result` line from the `if` branch
- in template, you need to render values: `a`, `b` and `result`, like

  ```
  <input type="text" name="a" value="{{ a }}"> +
  <input type="text" name="b" value="{{ b }}">
  <input type="submit" value="="> 
  <input type="text" name="result" value="{{ result }}">
  ```

Comment: or even more concise `request.POST.get('a', 0)` and `request.POST.get('b', 0)`

Comment: can I combine within one try-except block like this:
 
 `try:
    a = int(request.POST.get('a', 0))
    b = int(request.POST.get('b', 0))
  except:
    a = 0
    b = 0`

I've tested it, it works fine as well but not sure if this is a good practice to do so?
@okm @MikeDeSimone

Comment: @user1282634 its OK, you could narrow to `except ValueError` if you afraid possible unexpected error been caught.

Comment: I recommended separate `try` blocks so that only the broken input gets changed to `0`.